# Calculating a mean from multiple delimited values

Tags: python, pandas

I have many excel files that are used as a notebook/piece of paper, but the template is the same. I am trying to create a single dataframe from them.

Many cells have multiple numeric values for price, and I would like to extract those and find their average, excluding calendar years (e.g.2019).

Let's say the text in the cell is: USD 590K was minimum in 2019. USD650K is an initial offer.
But I never know how many numeric values are in there, could be 1 could be 5.

What I would like, is to get an average of all values excluding year. So in this instance:
(590+650)/2=620

This is what I've got so far:

```
s=df['Price'].str.findall('\d+')
df['Price1'] = s.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(i for i in x if int(i)<2000))
```

This gives an output of:

```
590_650
```

And then to get a mean:

```
df['Price1'].str.split('_').apply(lambda x : (float(x[0])+float(x[1]))/2)
```

However the problem with this is that I don't always have 2 values, it could be 1, it could be 5. So I would like something generic that can be applied anytime.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What if the text was `Offer was 2020 in 2020`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution without helper column with `join`:

```
s=df['Price'].str.findall('\d+')
df['Price2'] = s.apply(lambda x: np.mean([float(i) for i in x if int(i)<2000]))
```

Or:

```
s=df['Price'].str.extractall('(\d+)')
df['Price2'] = s[0].astype(float).loc[lambda x: x < 2000].groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Solution with helper column:

```
s=df['Price'].str.findall('\d+')
df['Price1'] = s.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(i for i in x if int(i)<2000))
df['Price2'] = df['Price1'].str.split('_', expand=True).astype(float).mean(axis=1)
```